# Saving MYSQL CSV to the server

Tags: php, mysql, output

I have some code which i am trying to use to generate a CSV file from MYSQL and then save it to the server.  The folder the file is trying to save to has the write property set. however when i run the code it throws an internal server error and i cant work out why.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
$query = "SELECT company_name FROM masterip_details 
INTO OUTFILE 'file.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' WHERE client_id='30' AND type='1'";
```

Comment: An internal server error (500) means you need to go and look in your error log for a more descriptive error message. Or display errors on screen: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: The directory needs to be writable by the web server user.

Comment: Looks like you have syntax issues - the `WHERE` clause follows the `FROM`, not the file info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: I thankyou i thought it might be the Where clauses so i removed them and still it happens, the folder is also writable by the web server user.

Comment: I also looked at the error log and there is nothing in there

Comment: If you get a 500 error from PHP and nothing is in  your error log, you need to turn on `log_errors` and crank up `error_reporting`.

Comment: Have you tried without `INTO OUTFILE`?

Comment: Can you make the query simpler?  Then add on the more complicated pieces so we can tell where it's going wrong.
Try: $query = "SELECT company_name FROM masterip_details;" INTO OUTFILE 'file.csv'"
It's possible that escaping out the slashes around file.csv might work: $query = "SELECT company_name FROM masterip_details;" INTO OUTFILE \'file.csv\'"

Comment: Reference to MySQL's webpage about this.. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html

Answer (score 0):

So i had set the folder on the server to chmod 777, and it appears that this was for some reason causing the internal server error as soon as i removed the write permissions the page started working.